# How to prove this that every previous roots satisfy the newer ones if we make it more complex?

Tags: proof-verification, recreational-mathematics, quadratics

We have $5-y^2=1$ ;it has 2 roots 2, -2.

Solving another way:

\begin{align} 
& 5-1×(y^2)=1 \\
\implies & 5-(5-y^2)y^2=1 \\
\implies & 5-5y^2 + y^4 =1 \\
\implies & y^4 -5y^2 +4×1=0 \\
\implies & y^4 -5y^2 +4×(5-y^2) =0 \\
\implies & y^4-9y^2 +20=0 
\end{align} 
has roots two extra roots.
Now, this is confusing as this thing can be done to any other random equation and if we keep on doing this we will be getting infinity roots. So for every equation there exist infinity roots which are hidden.
Please guide me as I want to know where am I going wrong?
Ok i understood that. Now if we go on doing this say if the 4 in power of y is multiplied by 1. And even the coefficients and we go on getting equations will 2,-2 always satisfy the new equation? To be more precise, will the roots of previous equation always satisfy the roots of newer equation? How do I prove it?

Comment: If you add roots, you no longer have a quadratic.  “Multiplying by a quantity that is sometimes $1$” is not the same as “multiplying by $1$.”

Comment: When you change your quadratic to make it a polynomial of degree four it can have four roots. Please write mathematics with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I dont really know how to use mathjax.thanks for the link.

Comment: I know that the biquadratic equation 's root i obtained will not satisfy the origibal one but does that meant none of the equation we know are real

Comment: @abiessu then by your logic if x+y=1 then x+y+x+y =2 is wrong by your logic as x+y is not always equal to 1?

Comment: Multiplying an equation by $2$ is equivalent to what happens in $x+y=1\to x+y+x+y=1+1$.  In your question, you multiplied part of an equation (not every part) by a quantity ($5-y^2$) that can be $1$, and this introduced extra values that the quantity ($5-y^2$) could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mathematicians answered your question in their edits with the use of $\implies$ in place of your original "or".

What the symbol means is: *If* the previous statement is true (e.g. $5-1 \times y^2=1$), *then* so is the following statement ($5-(5-y^2)y^2=1$). In this case, you go from one statement to the next by a substitution (to be honest I'm not sure where others are getting the idea that you multiplied two equations?).

The important point is that you cannot go in the *reverse* direction: every root of $5-y^2=1$ is also a root of $5-(t-y^2)y^2=1$, but not the other way around, because there's no way to derive the former equation from the latter (unless you split into cases).

Answer (score 0):

> By **multiplying** the same equation to your equation, you make a **higher** order equation but with unwanted roots. It is like saying $x=a$ so $(x-a)(x-a)=0*0\to x=+a,-a$

Let's make the problem simple by this example:

We can certainly say if $x=1$,  so  $x+1=2$ is also correct. They are both the same and not independent equations.

However, by **multiplying** them you make a **higher** order equation like below:

$(x)(x+1)=1*2=2 \to x^2+x-2=0$

The roots of this equation are $1$ and $-2$.
But we know that $-2$ is not really "the root" and is an unwanted root.

The *real reason* is that you should not multiply the **roots** of a system only due to the fact that they are correct or equal to 1 or so. Because it is like saying $0*x=0*y$. Continueing our problem:

$x^2+x-2=0 \to (x-1)*(x-2)=0 \to$ $($**any number**$)*(x-1)=0$ [because $x-1=0$]

Answer (score -2):

Let me correct a misconception of yours..?.
It need not be nessessary that a quadratic eq should have only 2 roots...
If u consider a quadratic eq in identity then it possesses not just 3 or 90... It possesses infinite number of roots
I suppose u know what is a quadratic eq in identity..
Hope this helps..

Comment: No but a quadratic has to have 2 roots. What i obtained is biquadratic.

Comment: I am not talking about identities! Simply about hidden equations

Comment: @Jasmine I think what the answerer is trying to say (in an unnecessarily obfuscated manner...) is that if $f = ax^2+bx+c$ is a quadratic with infinitely many roots, then $f=0$.

Comment: @Dustan possibly yes.